# How to get the expired sessions id from iis7 using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis-7, session-state

I need to get the list of expired session ids from iis 7 , I have tried the below code, but it gives only a current session id only..

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID.ToString()
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114639/how-do-i-know-which-users-session-id-has-been-expired-and-which-users-are-onli

Comment: i need the expired or active session ids list

Comment: I m using session state only

Comment: you can not get the expired session id list as they are also reused