# How to track active YT players the user has on the website even if the PC shuts down?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cron, user-tracking

I'm creating an application, which counts how much time the user spends watching YT videos on my website. Based on the time, later they will get some kind of rewards.

There is a security issue here: how can I stop them from watching two players at the same time? I've tried using solutions, like:

- Local Storage
- Session Storage
- PHP `$_SESSION`
- Global variables

And nothing worked. After some time of research, I've understood that it's only a `front-end` and I can't transfer this information to the different computers, browsers, etc.

Ok, so I gave a chance to the database. It can't be changed so easily like "Local Storage" or "Session Storage", however, it still has some problems I'm gonna list below.

---

Image the user logs into the website and starts playing a video. Using `YT Embed API` I've programmed so the database records would change to "active_players"  1. And this number **can't be bigger than 1**. Everything worked as expected until one thing happened:

**I couldn't subtract 1 from 1 if the user closes the browser, the computer suddenly shuts down or the browser tab gets closed**.

Yes, I could throw an alert box using the `window.onbeforeunload` method but it can be bypassed pretty easily just by checking the box to block these types of messages. It also wouldn't solve the unexpected behavior of computer like shutting down, etc.

---

I have an idea how I could do this theoretically:

First of all, send `AJAX` requests to the server database every 1 second and do something with the database records (update it or insert and remove some data).

When using `cron jobs` every 1-second check for the database results if they are still updating or not.

I don't know exactly how it should be done and it's my first time working with these types of things.

---

Similar post to mine: [How to know if the user is still online on the website or offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903081/how-to-know-if-the-user-is-still-online-on-the-website-or-offline)

Maybe we already have much better alternatives I don't know yet :) Help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Fyi, the smallest unit a cronjob can run is "minutes".

Comment: Yes, so sad :( Any ideas?